# Customising the WiX Burn theme with additional inputs

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I'm looking at using Burn as a bootstrapper for an installer and I need to pass in a couple of arguments into the MSI.

I know that the way to do this is to use `MsiProperty` elements, the issue I am having is with displaying the UI to capture those properties.  I'm aware that I can create a completely custom UI via the managed bootstrapper application host, however this is turning out to be a lot of work to implement for a relatively minor tweak to the bootstrapper.

I've found [this blog article](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/burn-ui-customisations.html) with describes how to do basic UI customisations and wondered if its possible to modify the Burn UI to include a simple checkbox / textbox (whose value is then use to set a Burn variable so I can pass it into my MSI) in a similar way, or do I need to use the managed bootstrapper application host after all?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I cant find any documentation on this anywhere, but a little bit of experimentation + reading through the source code reveals that this is fairly straightforward - just set the `Name` of the control (e.g. Checkbox) to the name of a Burn variable (not a WiX variable - they are different), like so (see [Burn UI Customisations](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/burn-ui-customisations.html) for more info on where to put this)

```
<Checkbox Name="MyCheckBox" ...>Hello, checkbox</Checkbox>
```

If you like you can define a burn variable beneath your bundle to initialise it to some value (use 1 for "ticked" and 0 for "unticked" with checkboxes)

```
<Variable Name="MyCheckBox" Value="1" />
```

However its not required - the variable will be created automatically for you anyway.  Note that it needs to be a `Variable`, not a `WixVariable` - these are different.

Finally to set an MSI property based on this variable add a [`MsiProperty`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msiproperty.htm) element as a child of your [`MsiPackage`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_msipackage.htm) element, like so

```
<MsiPackage Name="MyMsi.msi" ...>
    <MsiProperty Name="SOMEPROPERTY" Value="[MyCheckBox]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

The value of the MSI property "SOMEPROPERTY" will then be set to 0 or 1 based on the checked state of your checkbox.

Comment: I also use this method - it works. Probably safe to accept this as an answer :)

Comment: Great help thanks, however I was getting SOMEPROPERTY="" being passed to the MSI until I defined in the <Variable... in the <bundle> .. Looks like its not automatically created.

Comment: Does this solution only applies for checkbox or is it valid for EditBox too ? I am having issues in setting value of variable through EditBox