# Detect MSI package upgrade from bundle

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, installshield, wix3.9

I'm looking to move from InstallShield LE to Wix.

InstallShield generates and Foobar.Exe file. I've ran it with /b argument and then used dark.exe to generate wxs code.

I've created an MSI package (Foobar.msi) with the same upgrade code and a Bundle with a Chain with some prerequisites and the Foobar.msi and DIsplayInternaUI=true. The upgrade from InstallShield to Wix works as expected.

However, I'd like the Bundle to handle all UI, like [Rob Mensching recommends](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/6/25/b-is-for-bundle-and-thats-good-enough-for-me/) (currently I have two). How can the Bundle know the MSI is being upgraded? Because I need to show some dialogs only on first install (various system settings).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet because of my rep, so I will have to put it here as an answer.

So you need to get information from the user for the install?  Is that what the problem is here?

You can put some checkboxes or radio buttons on the install page or options page to pass variables to your MSI, this is possible in the extended bootstrapper, which has been put into Wix since 3.8.

Reference links:-

https://wixextba.codeplex.com/

[Customising the WiX Burn theme with additional inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323106/customising-the-wix-burn-theme-with-additional-inputs)